# unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR PHP error

Tags: php, sql, session

I get the error on the "if (!LoginODR ->EOF) { Line, I can't find any help online that relates directly to the same kind of statement I am making.

Thanks.

```
if (!LoginODR -> EOF) {

$SecurityLevel = $Loginodr ->Fields('Seclevel')->Value;

$_SESSION['IsValid']="Yes";
$_SESSION['security'] = $SecurityLevel;

}else {

    $_SESSION['IsValid']="No";
    echo "<center>Invalid Username or Password!</center>";
    echo "<br><br>";
    echo "<form method='post' action='Login.php' name='formcontact' id='formcontact'>";
    echo "<center><input type='submit' name='btnback' id='btnback' value='Back' style='width: 150px; height: 50px;'></center>";

}
```

Comment: Should that be `$Loginodr` instead of `LoginODR` (base on the next line)?

Comment: Constants cannot have properties. Spot the difference between `LoginODR -> EOF` and `$Loginodr ->Fields`.

Comment: I fixed the capitalization difference between LoginODR and Loginodr so they match but I still get the error.

Comment: Replacing the ! with a "$" just causes variable errors however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (!$LoginODR->EOF) {

$SecurityLevel = $LoginODR->Fields('Seclevel')->Value;

$_SESSION['IsValid']="Yes";
$_SESSION['security'] = $SecurityLevel;

}else {

    $_SESSION['IsValid']="No";
    echo "<center>Invalid Username or Password!</center>";
    echo "<br><br>";
    echo "<form method='post' action='Login.php' name='formcontact' id='formcontact'>";
    echo "<center><input type='submit' name='btnback' id='btnback' value='Back' style='width: 150px; height: 50px;'></center>";

}
```